# Сделать разгоняющийся объект на C# Unity

Tags: c#, unity3d

Нужно сделать так чтобы ракета разгонялась потихоньку ну в идеале чтобы она реалестично разгонялась.Вот пример моего скрипта

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class NewBehaviourScript : MonoBehaviour {
    public Transform EndPoint;
    // Use this for initialization
    void Start () {

    }

    // Update is called once per frame
    void Update () {
        int b = 1;
        b += 1;
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position,EndPoint.position,b);
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> из документации...

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;

public class ExampleClass : MonoBehaviour
{
    // The target marker.
    public Transform target;

    // Speed in units per sec.
    public float speed;

    void Update()
    {
        // The step size is equal to speed times frame time.
        speed++;
        float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;

        // Move our position a step closer to the target.
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
    }
}
```

Comment: Да всё правильно,а как сделать ограничение скорости? ` if (step == 100)
        {
            step = 100;
        }`

Comment: Переписать строку `speed++;` на `if (speed < 100) speed++;` 100 - можно запихнуть в переменную в public

Comment: Во работает только я по своему сделал а что такое Time.deltaTime это число или переменная ? просто слишком быстро скорость набирается можно его в 2 раза замедлить? даже если переменную speed ставишь на 0.00000001 то одинакого разгоняется

Comment: `public Transform target;
    public float maxspeed = 100;
    // Speed in units per sec.
    public float speed = 0.01f;
    float speedUp = 1;
    void Update()
    {
        // The step size is equal to speed times frame time.
        speed++;
        float step = speed * Time.deltaTime;
        // Move our position a step closer to the target.
        if (speed >= maxspeed)
        {
            speed = maxspeed;
        }
        transform.position = Vector3.MoveTowards(transform.position, target.position, step);
    }
}`